# Getting an error on Breadwallet when I run the app on Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitcoin

I am getting an error that unable to resolve it.
Please check the below image.[image]

I have downloaded the code from https://github.com/voisine/breadwallet

Please help me.

Comment: Try to clean build the project.

Comment: @NiravD, I have tried a lots of time but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

**APPLE LLVM 8.0 ERROR**

The issue was generated by "wrong" path in Build Setting.

I thought it should require the path in my computer like $(SRCROOT)/Classes, instead I had to enter the file path in the project Classes/Header-name-file

Comment: That's a completely different issue.